# How to implement multi-select?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2016

First of all, I need to say that I never worked with Access or any other databases before. I'm trying to understand how it works and picked "Students" template for this task (see step 0). Now, let's start.

## i. Creating the base from the template and fill it with data

**Step 0**. Creating new database based on "Students" template:

[image]

**Step 1**. On the objects pane (i.e. left sidebar) search for *Student List* form and double-click on it:

[image]

Fill the *First Name* and *Last Name* for the first student: it will be Mike Smith.

In the *Special Circumstances* column it is possible to select **multiple** circumstances: for example, *Circumstance 1* and *Circumstance 2*. And if you click on the icon below the combo-box, it is possible to edit the list of available check-boxes:

[image]

**Step 2**. After we have created the entry for the first student, double-click on the *Guardian List* form and create entries for 3 guardians: Jane Roe, John Doe and Jill Joe.

**Step 3**. Return to the *Student List* form. Click on the *Open* cell in front of *Mike Smith*. It will be opened *Student details* form for this student. When it will be opened, click on *Guardian Information* tab - and you will see, that all 3 guardians are available for combo-box:

[image]

## ii. Now, my task

- I want to see the guardians directly in the *Student List* form - the same way as *Special Circumstances* located.
- I want to get the option to select multiple guardians for each student - the same way as *Special Circumstances* check-boxes are implemented.

## iii. How it was solved myself, but only the 1st point of the task

To simplify the task, I will use *Student ID* column (located on the *Student List* form), instead of creating new column.

On the left sidebar - click on *Student List* form with right mouse button and then select *Design View*. When *Design View* will be opened, select *Student ID* field, right click on it, then click *Change To* and *Combo Box*:

[image]

Then, on the right sidebar select *Data* tab, set curson inside *Row Source* field and then click small ellipsis (...). In the *Show Table* window select *Guardians* and then click *Add* button and close this small window.

[image]

[image]

Then, in the large window, do this:

[image]

And then click *Save As* and *Close* on the ribbon.

Then, switch the *Student List* form back to the *Layout view* (the same way, as we switched it early to *Design View*). And you will see that the first point of my task is solved: the last names of guardians are available in *Student ID* column:

[image]

But how I can implement multiselect, the same way as it is implemented in *Special Circumstances* column? So, Mike could have both Jane Roe and John Doe as his guardians.

Comment: Most newer ask'ers that I refer to "[mcve]" is because they don't include enough detail. Your reason is the opposite; link is the same.  :)  Are you able to summarize your question into 1-2 sentences for me so I don't have to read all that?  Then I may be able to help!  This site gets 15,000 posts per day.  If they were ***all*** this long, there'd be a lot fewer answered questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-valued combo boxes are very odd controls. Avoid them whenever possible.

Creating an unbound multi-valued combo box is not possible (see [How can I create a Multiple Value Combo box on an Unbound Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1570745/7296893)). A combo box is multi-valued when the field it is bound to is multi-valued, or when it's set to a multi-valued lookup.

To change a field to a multi-valued field, you need to alter the table design, and set the *Allow multiple values* property to *Yes*:

[image]

This will automatically change any combo boxes bound to this field to multi-valued combo boxes.

Note that I highly recommend not using this approach. This database already demonstrates a junction table, the recommended way to manage many-to-many relationships. Using junction tables and multi-valued combo boxes is not possible without using very hacky techniques.

Comment: For futher readers: here is a tutorial of how to use intermediate tables (also known as "junction tables"): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-create-many-to-many-relationships-e65bcc53-8e1c-444a-b4fb-1c0b8c1f5653